# Adding text on each bar in horizontal bar plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add text (`n`) on each bar in a horizontal bar plot in `ggplot` environment, but keep getting error message, I wonder what will be correct way to do so?
Also, I tried to invoke `viridis` package to add color on those bars but can't seem to get around. Is there any way to map different colors to those bars?

My current code is shown at below.

```
    # the data

    city_r <- data.frame(
    City = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
    rating = c(5.52, 8, 6.24, 5.89, 5.57, 8.67),
    n = c(112, 1, 25, 40, 9, 36)
                     )
    # rating means mayor's rating
    # n means respondents' size in each city

    library(ggplot2)

    # plot it
    g <- city_r %>% 
      group_by(City) %>% 
      arrange(rating) %>% 
      ggplot(., mapping = aes(x=reorder(City, rating), y =rating))+
      geom_text(aes(n), colour = "black", position = "dodge") +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.8, position = position_dodge(width = .25))+
      labs(
        title = "",
        y = "Mayor's rating",
        x = ""
      )+
      coord_flip()
      
     g
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming your error is

```r
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

This is because your `geom_text` is using `aes(n)`, where the default first-arg of `aes` is `x=`, not what I think you intend, `label=`.

Fixing that and adding `hjust=-0.5` (for an offset), then we can add `aes(fill=City)` to the bars in order to *start* the colors, then add the scale itself.

```r
g <- city_r %>% 
  group_by(City) %>% 
  arrange(rating) %>% 
  ggplot(., mapping = aes(x=reorder(City, rating), y =rating))+
  geom_text(aes(label=n), hjust=-0.5, colour = "black", position = "dodge") +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=City), stat = "identity", width=.8, position = position_dodge(width = .25))+
  labs(
    title = "",
    y = "Mayor's rating",
    x = ""
  )+
  coord_flip() +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
g
# Warning: Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

- To remove the legend, add `guide=NULL` to the scale.
- To move the numbers to the middle of the bars, you need to both (a) add a new `y=` aesthetic to `geom_text`, *and* change the order of geoms (since if the bars are added second, then they will completely obscure the numbers).

New code:

```r
g <- city_r %>% 
#   group_by(City) %>% 
#   arrange(rating) %>% 
#   ggplot(., mapping = aes(x=reorder(City, rating), y =rating))+
#   geom_bar(aes(fill=City), stat = "identity", width=.8, position = position_dodge(width = .25))+
#   geom_text(aes(label=n, y=rating/2), hjust=-0.5, colour = "black", position = "dodge") +
#   labs(
#     title = "",
#     y = "Mayor's rating",
#     x = ""
#   ) +
#   coord_flip() +
#   viridis::scale_fill_viridis(guide=NULL, discrete=TRUE)
g
# Warning: Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, is there a way to remove that vertical factor bar on the right? Also, I want to put those numbers in the middle of the bar, so that the right side of the plot won't get too congested.

Comment: Removing the legend is pretty simple, plenty of questions on SO cover that (I'm not at my computer so cannot test). The `y` aesthetic is inherited from the original call, your can override it by using something like `aes(label=n, y=rating/2)`.